# How to filter an array using another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm in a situation where I need to filter an array based off another array that is generated from the user. I've managed to get it to work for a single value from the user but I can't expand it out to an array from the user. Below is an example of the array ('comments') to be filtered:

```
[
{postId: 1, content: "XXX"},
{postId: 2, content: "XXX"},
{postId: 2, content: "XXX"},
{postId: 3, content: "XXX"}
]
```

I then receive an input from the user into an array which would be like:

```
[1,2]
```

In this example, the output I would want is:

```
[
{postId: 1, content: "XXX"},
{postId: 2, content: "XXX"},
{postId: 2, content: "XXX"}
]
```

Here is the code I use to get the user input from a form:

```
function formSubmit() {
        const lookupVals = document
            .getElementById('post-id-input')
            .value.split(',')
            .filter(Boolean);
        console.log(lookupVals);
        filterComments(lookupVals);
    }
```

And, then I use the below function to filter the original array after the form has been submitted:

```
function filterComments(filterVals) {
        try {
            console.log(comments.filter(comment => comment.postId == filterVals));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

I managed to get it work with the one value by using the .filter method on the original array 'comments' and checking if the postID is equal to the value passed in the form from the user. But, I'm struggling to expand it out to accept multiple values as this currently works with an array but it can only contain one value.

So far I've had no luck with using a second .filter or trying to use .includes.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

```
comments.filter(comment => filterVals.includes(comment.postId))
```

Comment: That's such a common task that there is definitely a dupe target (as you can see)...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution. I believe this will work but it is currently due to I believe the input from the user being a string, is there a way I could convert the code in the above code example, to make it record an array of ints rather than strings. I know the .split() method makes it a string but could it be converted back using .parseInt()?

Comment: @ConerMurphy, `.value.split(',').filter(Boolean).filter(Number)` will convert the items back to number:)

Comment: @Mamun Yes i believe so because the .split() returns an array of strings split? Would it be better to redo this bit of code to remove this and leave them as ints in the original array?

Comment: @Mamun I just did what I mentioned above and it now works but the issue I've got now is the original array has values going from 1 - 500 for postId's and if I filter by '15' I get the posts with the id: 1, 5 and 15 as they contain these ints. I think this is why I originally split the array into strings of each value to prevent this? Any Ideas?

Comment: I just tried converting this with the code you mentioned above but they are still console logging as strings so I don't think it worked? Not sure why?

Comment: @ConerMurphy, `[1,2,3,4...,15,.....499,500].filter(i => i==15)` will give you just 15, not 1,5 and 15

Comment: @ConerMurphy, may be you can update the question with sample data for which the code is not working:)

Comment: @Mamun I managed to get it work with `.value.split(',').filter(Boolean).map(int => parseInt(int));`, this seems to work now and I can filter the original array with the input array and log them out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ConerMurphy, that's really grate. I was wrong, I mentioned `filter` instead of `map`.........should be `.value.split(',').filter(Boolean).map(Number)`.........

Comment: @Mamun Just curious, what does the Number do inside the .map(Number)? Is this just a short hand way of changing the type of value to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```js
comments.filter(comment => filterVals.includes(comment.postId))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
   {postId: 1, content: "XXX"},
   {postId: 2, content: "XXX"},
   {postId: 2, content: "XXX"},
   {postId: 3, content: "XXX"}
];

const input = [1,2];

const filtered = arr.filter(i => input.includes(i.postId));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: That's such a common task that there is definitely a dupe target (as you can see)...